# How to loop through requests using cypress?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, web, automated-tests, cypress

```
  function AssertResponseCode200(request) {
    cy.wait(request).then(response => {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
    });
  }

  function CheckDictionaries() {
    var requestUrls = [
      "requestUrl1",
      "requestUrl2",
      "..."
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < requestUrls.length; i++) {
      cy.route("GET", requestUrls[i]).as(`request${i}`);
      AssertResponseCode200(`@request${i}`);
    }
  }

  it("Assert dictionaries", () => {
    cy.server();
    CheckDictionaries();
});
```

[image]

`CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'request1'. No request ever occurred.`

I want to cycle through requests and check that everything works fine and response code is 200. But I'm stuck, because the only url that gets aliased is the first one in my array, but I need all elements of my `requestUrls` array to be aliased with `request${i}`. Is there anything wrong with my code, or routes in cypress can not work with for loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem you have is because you're waiting for only one request to finish each time but the requests finish asynchronously in random order so sometimes you might be waiting for a request that has already completed.

`cy.wait()` accepts also an array of aliases so you can first collect all aliases and then wait for all of them with a single `cy.wait()`.

```
const aliases = [];
for (let i = 0; i < requestUrls.length; i++) {
  aliases.push(`@request${i}`);
  ...
}

cy.wait(aliases);
```